# Web Service Security - Basic Authentication

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am new to web service world. I have created SOAP web service and web client pointing to that service in axis and everything working fine, Now I want to add basic authentication to my web service. how can I write username and password to message header at client side and retrieve both in my web service for validation????

Comment: Could you please show us what have you tried?

Comment: yah sure I tried it one way. I am unable to share my code. bt at client side i used SOAPHeaderElement object and called addChildElement method of it to set usename and password. and at server side i used WebServiceContext and MessageContext to retrive those fields but getting null. Thanx in Advance :)